# How to extract Google Instant answers using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1024x768")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

def ask_google(query):

    # Search for query
    query = query.replace(' ', '+')

    driver.get('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + query)

    # Get text from Google answer box

    answer = driver.execute_script(
            "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);",
            350, 230).text

    return answer
```

I tried to extract google instant answers using with the help of Selenium and chrome driver using python, but when I run the it shows this error

> (1126/125608.919:ERROE:gpuprocess_transport_factory.cc<980>l Lost UI
>   shared con ext.  IleuTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:63320/deutools/browser/19540456-8dd5-4f7a-9
>   .25-fb3dd0E60000

[image]

i want this as the answer

```
ask_google("what is the time in US")

"4:36 PM"

ask_google("What is a car")

"a road vehicle, typically with four wheels, powered by an internal combustion engine and able to carry a small number of people.
```

can somebody please help me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it non Fatal error you can ignore it with

```
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=3')
```

it not showing text in the console maybe because it missing `print()`? and it need additional action to get `"a road vehicle, typically....` see below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1024x768")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

def ask_google(query):
    # Search for query
    query = query.replace(' ', '+')
    driver.get('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + query)

    # Get text from Google answer box
    answer = driver.execute_script("return document.elementFromPoint(350, 230);").text

    try:
        answer += "\n" + driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-dobid="dfn"]/span').text
    except: pass

    return answer

the_answer = ask_google("What is a car")
print(the_answer)
driver.close()
```

Comment: i tried to run it but it gives this error " line 1, in <module>
    chrome_options = Options()
NameError: name 'Options' is not defined"

Comment: add module import, see your code above

Comment: thank you so much ewwink it works!!!

Comment: you're welcome, if solved please mark the answer as correct.